# Efficient Access to Large Arrays in Documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently working on a web app using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [mongodb](http://mongodb.org/) and [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). The logical structure of the model that I'm dealing with is a collection of documents where each document contains an array of subdocuments. Hence, the straightforward mongoose schema would look something like:

```
{
    "key": {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}},
    // further document properties
    "subdocuments": [subschema] 
}
```

However, I suspect that it is not a good idea to design the model this way, for the following reason: The arrays can grow potentially large. Also, the queries that I need to perform on a regular basis are of the following kind:

- Find all subdocuments in a specific range of a document A. (e.g., A.subdocuments.0 .. A.subdocuments.10).
- Find the document in the array with the highest index.

Does someone have a suggestion how to remodel this?

Comment: Is there a requirement to stick with mongodb? While nested documents are available in NoSQL databases, they should generally be kept simple (few sub-docs/small amounts of data) to respect and gain the benefits a document-based database offers.  Also, this is kind of question leads to somewhat subjective answers (like this comment)...you might try a few things and then ask about specific performance issues or ways to simplify the code you write and use.

Comment: The project is in an early stage and there is no requirement that says we have to stay with mongodb. On other hand, so far, the requirements seemed not to contradict the choice–and, while I'm not a particular fan of NoSQL-databases, the combination of node.js and mongodb seems to be a popular choice and hence there is support. What would you suggest as an alternative to mongodb?

Comment: It's popular, but node has good support for pretty much any database out there.  MySQL, PostgreSQL, Mongo, elasticsearch, etc.  Pick one you know.  A local rule of thumb is that if working with NoSQL but finding the need for queries that mimic a SQL join and will likely involve many sub-docs...we pause and ask if it's time to consider our database selection before we commit to something in production that may wind up causing us maintenance headaches (building faux-joins in NoSQL) or performance issues (searching hundreds/thousands of sub-docs). Good luck!  :)

Comment: No need to swap out the entire dabtase... why don't you just use two collections? "Faux Joins" are only a problem if they are truly joins, which isn't the case here - searching related documents in a certain range is a simple, straightforward query. In any case, large embedded arrays are a bad idea.

Comment: The Subdocument could be a separate collection with a compound index comprising the primary key of A and the number.

Comment: with two schemas and the SubdocSchema referencing the MainSchema, you can do the queries you mentioned. Schemas are less about relationships and more about ease of queries (within reason)